# py.test -n with Django TestCase urls

Tags: django, unit-testing, pytest

To use a specific url-config in your Django tests all you have to do is specify it:

```
class MyTests(TestCase):
    urls = 'myproj.myapp.urls'

    def test_myurl(self):
        r = self.client.get('/foo/')  # looks up /foo/ in myproj/myapp/urls.py
```

it doesn't look like the implementation is thread-safe however:

```
def _urlconf_setup(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'urls'):
        self._old_root_urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
        settings.ROOT_URLCONF = self.urls
        clear_url_caches()
```

and I'm seeing 404 errors in my test-log after I run the test-suite with py.test -n8 (using all 8 cpus).

Has anyone else seen/solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: setting `urls` on your `TestCase` subclass is not thread safe when called `from py.test -n`, presumably because the different threads are clobbering `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`.

There is code in `django/core/handlers/base.py:get_response()` (I just checked the latest revision too) which will fetch urlconf from the request object if present, instead of using `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`.

The solution then, is to attach the value of `self.urls` to the `request` object that `Client.py` passes to the view function. We haven't seen any problems after implementing this fix, running 1100+ tests with `-n8`.

(If you already have your own copies of `client.py` and `testcases.py`, it is relatively easy (~14 loc) to remove the current urlconf machinery from `_pre_setup` and instead pass `self.urls` through Client so ClientHandler can attach it to `request` before calling `self.get_response()`.)

Comment: @Ronny you are probably correct, however (without reading the code too deeply) it seems like it distributes tests among available processes, in such a way that tests from UnitTest subclasses with different `urls` fail to reset Django's settings proxy.  If you have an easier or less invasive solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The `py.test -n8`invocation will start 8 subprocesses.  Is there maybe an issue with starting 8 django servers and accessing them via `self.client(...)`, i.e. a fixed default port that is used by each of them?

Update: Also, you might want to install the [pytest-django plugin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-django) and see if it helps with running your tests with `-n 8`.

Comment: No, the django TestCase and Client implementation only mimics a web server. Under the covers it just uses WSGI operations, i.e. no network traffic is happening.

Comment: The pytest-django plugin looks interesting. I'll keep it in mind when we've upgraded to Django 1.3 :-(

Answer (score 1):

i wonder if the default test database you use is save for use with N test processes at once

Comment: I'm using a mounted copy of last night's backup, so yes it is.

Comment: the problem i mean is that - what happens for example if one test process deletes something, that another test process wants to open at the same time

Comment: That is a valid concern, but we've taken great care making sure each test method that mutates data work on separate records or create their own records and delete them afterwards.